# Criptografar arquivos ini

Tags: php, c#, linux, visual-studio, criptografia

Eu preciso de um *script* que compile um `.ini` para evitar uma leitura fácil. O arquivo deve ser lido com o PHP. Parece que o C# tem um recurso semelhante. A pergunta é como eu faço isso e depois leio o `.ini` com o PHP.

Exemplo do arquivo `.ini`:

```
[db_production]
host = db_production.fiber01.intraservers
type = mssql
user = db_user
pass = db_pass
namedb = db_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Se esta resposta não é boa o suficiente, favor verificar minha outra resposta para esta pergunta, ao invés de ficar negativando a resposta que serviu ao autor da pergunta e que pode servir para outras pessoas no futuro.

Você pode codificar seu resultado em [`Base64`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Fica assim:

```
W2RiX3Byb2R1Y3Rpb25dDQpob3N0ID0gZGJfcHJvZHVjdGlvbi5maWJlcjAxLmludHJhc2VydmVycw0KdHlwZSA9IG1zc3FsDQp1c2VyID0gZGJfdXNlcg0KcGFzcyA9IGRiX3Bhc3MNCm5hbWVkYiA9IGRiX25hbWU=
```

Codificando `Base64` em C#:

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

Decodificando em C#:

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
    var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

Codificando `Base64` em PHP:

```
$codificada = base64_encode($string);
```

Decodificando em PHP:

```
$original = base64_decode($codificada);
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, muito obrigado!!

Comment: sempre achei feio essa exposição da senha do db. Mts vezes é configurado em um xml, um ini um arquivo de texto simples. É uma duvida interessante.

Comment: @HiagoSouza O problema é que base64 não é uma criptografia de fato e há até sites para desembaralhar um texto codificado: https://www.base64decode.org/ (e só de olhar o texto codificado já fica óbvio que é base64). Se você quer de fato impedir a leitura, use criptografia de verdade, como uma TripleDES. C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes(v=vs.110).aspx. PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php.

Comment: Sim mais a partir disso eu posso modificar a string e gerar uma classe própria entende? se eu coloco uma virgula em algum lugar o retorno já não será o mesmo.

Comment: @HiagoSouza Se você colocar uma vírgula, eu tiro porque sei que ela não faz parte de uma representação base64 :-) Mas eu entendi seu ponto - no final você vai acabar fazendo uma criptografia na mão; só que isso vai te dar algum trabalho e possivelmente ainda assim nenhuma segurança. É mais fácil e seguro usar TripleDES.

Comment: isso é sem vergonha, melhor ficar sem essa criptografia,  qual é o motivo disso?

Comment: @Caffé minha unica preocupação era de uma fácil visualização da senha entende, eu procuro dificultar o acesso a essa informação só isso.

Comment: @ÉdipoCostaRebouças me desculpe mais em momento algum eu falei em segurança eu disse que queria dificultar a leitura.

Comment: é que se alguém  estiver  mal intencionado e com acesso ao seu servidor,  não  é o base 64 que vai impedir. você  está  dificultando  leitura deste iní por segurança,  não tem outro motivo pra isso.  eu entendo que a resposta respondeu sua pergunta,  mas como  profissional tenho que falar que isso e nada  é a mesma coisa.

Comment: @ÉdipoCostaRebouças ok obrigado, agradeço a ajuda de todos. É sempre bom questionarmos agrega mais conhecimento e experiência.

Comment: @ÉdipoCostaRebouças Existe uma diferença entre proteger uma "senha" e proteger um **"segredo"** - como no caso a "senha" não é aquilo que desbloqueia o acesso ao aplicativo em si, mas sim que desbloqueia o acesso a alguma outra coisa (o BD) a forma de proteção tem que ser diferente. No caso, é muito difícil dar uma proteção adequada a um custo razoável (que não envolva, por exemplo, guardar o segredo na memória e entrar de novo toda vez que der o boot), então o usual é guardar sem proteção mesmo. O base64 quando usado pra esse fim ajuda a prevenir acesso **acidental**, e não acesso malicioso.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que minha primeira resposta foi muito questionada, estou colocando aqui mais uma maneira de criptografar o conteúdo do arquivo .ini utilizado o algoritmo [`TripleDES`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DES).

O método `TripleDES` exige uma chave de criptografia (ou um *salt*, nome comum) que deve ser salva em algum lugar. Para os exemplos, suponha um *Helper* chamado `SettingsReader` que lê este valor de algum lugar.

Note que o `TripleDES` também usa `Base64` no algoritmo.

Codificando `TripleDES` em C#:

```
public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)
{
    byte[] keyArray;
    byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

    System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = 
                                        new AppSettingsReader();

    // Obtendo a chave de segurança do arquivo de configuração.

    string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", 
                                                     typeof(String));
    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(key);
    //If hashing use get hashcode regards to your key
    if (useHashing)
    {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        hashmd5.Clear();
    }
    else
        keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    tdes.Key = keyArray;

    // Há 5 modos de operação. O utilizado nessa resposta é o ECB (Electronic Code Book)
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    // O padding é o método definido para trabalhar com bytes residuais.
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] resultArray = 
      cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, 
      toEncryptArray.Length);
    tdes.Clear();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
}
```

Decodificando `TripleDES` em C#:

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherString, bool useHashing)
{
    byte[] keyArray;    
    byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString);

    System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = 
                                        new AppSettingsReader();
    string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", 
                                                 typeof(String));

    if (useHashing)
    {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        hashmd5.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    }

    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    tdes.Key = keyArray;

    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(
                         toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);           
    tdes.Clear();
    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
}
```

Codificando `TripleDES` em PHP:

```
function encrypt($input,$ky)
{
   $key = $ky;
   $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, 'ecb');
   $input = pkcs5_pad($input, $size);
   $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, '', 'ecb', '');
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
   mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
   $data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
   mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
   mcrypt_module_close($td);
   $data = base64_encode($data);
   $data = urlencode($data);
   return $data;
}
```

Decodificando `TripleDES` em PHP:

```
function decrypt($crypt,$ky)
{

    $crypt = urldecode($crypt);
    $crypt = base64_decode($crypt);
    $key = $ky;
    $td = mcrypt_module_open (MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, '', 'ecb', '');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $decrypted_data = mdecrypt_generic ($td, $crypt);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit ($td);
    mcrypt_module_close ($td);
    $decrypted_data = pkcs5_unpad($decrypted_data);
    $decrypted_data = rtrim($decrypted_data);
    return $decrypted_data;
}
```

Funções adicionais para cuidar do *padding*:

```
function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize)
{
   $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
   return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function pkcs5_unpad($text)
{
   $pad = ord($text{strlen($text)-1});
   if ($pad > strlen($text)) return false;
   return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
}
```

Comment: realmente não tem muito milagre, continua 6 por meia dúzia. mas não acredito que o problema é a resposta, mas sim a pergunta.

Comment: Sua primeira resposta está perfeita, o pessoal que está criticando não sabe o que está falando. Usar criptografia simétrica pra proteger senha e usar nada é praticamente a mesma coisa. E se um hash não se aplica (pois a senha original é indispensável ao funcionamento da aplicação), tentar adicionar "proteção" só vai dar uma ilusão de segurança, não segurança verdadeira.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Agradeço imensamente pela lucidez ;)