# Criptografia de senha

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, criptografia

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC e gostaria de guardar de forma segura as senhas dos usuários no banco.

O objetivo é criar algo que não possa ser descriptografado facilmente em algumas horinhas de força bruta em um PC (estou ciente que com um pouco mais de esforço a senha poderá ser quebrada). Logo, uma simples hash **não** seria o ideal, como: MD5, SHA1, SHA2, etc. Acredito que algum algorítimo simétrico como o AES resolveria o problema.

O que tenho planejado:

Ao criar a conta, a senha do usuário é criptografada e salva no banco de dados.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao realizar login, a senha do banco não será descriptografada, mas a senha digitada pelo usuário no login será criptografada e comparada com a senha do banco.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*Desconsidere se o **código** presente na imagem não esteja correto.*

> **As dúvidas são:**
>
> 1. Essa seria uma boa prática?
> 2. AES seria o melhor algorítimo?
>      2.1. Como poderia ser feita a criptografia AES usando C#? Já existe algum método pronto?
>      2.2. Existe algum modelo de chave mais segura?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101

Comment: [Dei duas respostas aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43604/criptografar-arquivos-ini/43681#43681). Não sei se é o caso de responder de novo, mas se precisar, é só falar.

Comment: Veja a pergunta que o bigown citou. Usar AES para proteger senhas é complicado, pois se um atacante ganha acesso ao seu servidor ele também ganha acesso à chave de criptografia simétrica... Uma criptografia assimétrica melhora as coisas um pouco (já que você nunca vai "inverter", você pode guardar a chave privada fora do servidor), mas ainda possui desvantagens em relação a um hash lento.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Essa seria uma boa prática?

Não. A [forma recomendada de proteger uma senha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101) é através de um hash lento (PBKDF2, BCrypt ou scrypt). Você está correto em dizer que um hash rápido é ineficaz, mas você percebe que usar um algoritmo de criptografia em uma única direção (só cifrar, nunca decifrar) é quase a mesma coisa que aplicar um hash?

Não seria honesto de minha parte dizer que sua técnica é de todo inútil, entretanto - se um atacante obtiver acesso ao banco de dados *e só ao banco de dados* (por exemplo, explorando uma Injeção de SQL) ele será incapaz de recuperar as senhas. De fato, existe uma técnica chamada *"pepper"* (pimenta) que se aproveita desse fato para dar proteção adicional a um hash (mais detalhes na resposta à pergunta linkada). O problema está em basear toda sua segurança somente nessa premissa (que o atacante não terá acesso ao seu código, nem que seja só pra leitura).

> AES seria o melhor algorítimo?

Nem AES nem nenhum outro algoritmo de criptografia simétrica (como o 3DES, etc). Pois mesmo que *você* não pretenda decifrar a senha em nenhum momento, um atacante que obtenha acesso ao seu BD e sua chave não vai fazer o mesmo "por questão de honra", ele vai é desfazer a criptografia e pronto! Ou seja, seu login fica lento (pois você fica cifrando e comparando) e o atacante continua rápido...

Uma cifra assimétrica seria marginalmente melhor (pois assim o atacante não poderia simplesmente decifrar, ele teria de testar senha por senha - pois se a chave privada está fora do servidor, ele só pode usar a chave pública) mas ela ainda corre o risco de ser excessivamente rápida em relação a um hash. No fim das contas, um hash é mesmo o melhor que você pode razoavelmente conseguir, e o uso de um *pepper* ajudaria a dar a segurança adicional que você buscou ao propor esse método (embora eu, pessoalmente, não costumo me preocupar demais com isso - vai depender do quão sensível é sua aplicação particular).

> Como poderia ser feita <del>a criptografia AES</del> um hash lento usando C#? Já existe algum método pronto?

O [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) é uma solução nativa para o PBKDF2 (existem também implementações BCrypt e scrypt para .Net, de terceiros creio eu), você só precisa ajustar os parâmetros de acordo. Um exemplo seria:

```
string pwd = senha_a_ser_hasheada;

// Cria um sal aleatório de 64 bits
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    // Enche o array com um valor aleatório
    rngCsp.GetBytes(salt);
}

// Escolha o valor mais alto que seja "tolerável"
// 100 000 era um valor razoável em 2011, não sei se é suficiente hoje
int myIterations = 100000;
try
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes k = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd, salt, myIterations);
    byte[] hash = k.getBytes(32);
    // Codifica esse hash de alguma forma e salva no BD
    // (lembre-se de salvar o salt também! você precisará dele para comparação)
```

Se quiser usar um *pepper*, pegue o valor secreto que só existe no seu código (ou em algum arquivo de configuração) e concatene-o à senha ou ao sal antes de realizar o hash (ajustando o tamanho se necessário).

Comment: Vi bons comentários, mas sua resposta foi espetacular. Existe algum limite em bits para o salt?  O que seria exatamente as interações? Olhei [nesse site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yx129kfs.aspx) consegui algumas informações, mas ficaram ainda essas duas dúvidas.

Comment: Não sei se existem limites, 8 bytes é o mínimo, mas pode ser mais se quiser (não vejo muito sentido em se usar mais bits no sal do que no hash gerado, entretanto). É mais importante que o sal seja **único** por usuário do que secreto, então você pode guardá-lo no banco junto ao hash sem proteção alguma. As iterações são o que tornam o hash lento - o PBKDF2 basicamente chama uma função de hash (no caso, o SHA-1, e tecnicamente falando é um HMAC e não um hash) repetidas vezes, e você é quem especifica o número de repetições. Isso estabelece um tempo mínimo necessário para o atacante tentar cada

Comment: candidato a senha. A documentação fala que 1000 é o mínimo recomendável, mas era o mínimo recomendável anos atrás, hoje em dia 10 000 ou mais é melhor (e as bibliotecas "sérias" usam 100 000 ou mais). Veja quanto tempo demora pra gerar um hash usando 100 000 no seu servidor, se achar que é lento demais diminua, senão aumente. O ideal é que o número seja o mais alto possível, desde é claro que o usuário não fique 10s esperando por um login hehe. Ah, e se você pretende mudar o número de iterações no futuro, guarde isso no banco também, senão os usuários antigos não conseguirão logar.

Comment: Um meio flexível é usando um campo "senha" que contenha `<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>`. Ex.: `PBKDF2$100000$kXNppmR0lbE=$oxRYXBtozKLv6KnAGQ==`. Assim no futuro seu sistema pode evoluir sem comprometer os usuários antigos.

Comment: neste caso um possível atacante não estaria com a faca e o queijo na mão?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Por que? A premissa de um hash bem feito é que dado um algoritmo, um fator de trabalho, um sal e um hash, não seja possível em tempo hábil encontrar uma senha que produza aquele mesmo hash (i.e. inverter o hash). Todos esses dados são necessários, pois para verificar se uma senha está ou não correta você vai ter que refazer esse processo.

Comment: Você está certo! Minha premissa de que o importante é não dar informações e criar uma senha "inquebrável" está errada. Durante a leitura dos resultados de minha pesquisa, percebi que o importante é que o tempo hábil para se quebrar essa hash impossibilite a tentativa do mesmo.

Comment: Você teria o link com essa citação? (i.e. inverter o hash)

Comment: ao usar o padrão '$' para separar os parâmetros em minha concatenação não existiria o risco de minha hash ser gerada também com '$' gerando assim problemas? Ou a hash NUNCA irá possuir '$'?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Não tenho uma citação específica, mas [o artigo da Wikipedia em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) explica razoavelmente bem essa propriedade ("resistência à pré-imagem" e "é impraticável gerar uma mensagem a partir do seu hash") - que é a razão de ser de uma função de hash criptográfico, aliás. Quanto ao `$`, eu me inspirei [na forma que o Django faz](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/passwords/). Se tanto o sal quanto o hash forem codificados em base64 (ou em hex, ou em decimal) então não tem como aparecer um `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Use bcrypt: https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt-Official.
Leia a definição do que é bcrypt: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt. 
Com bcrypt suas senhas são encriptadas já com salt/hash. 
Na verificação do usuário quando faz login, existe a função VerifyPassword que recebe 2 parâmetros os quais são: senha vindo do textbox e a senha vinda do banco de dados; faz-se a comparação dos hashes. 
Para usar, faça a inclusão dessas linhas de acordo com a linguagem escolhida:

```
using Bcrypt.Net.Bcrypt -> C# 
Imports Bcrypt.Net.Bcrypt -> VB.NET
```

Para fazer o hash da senha:

```
HashPassword(senha, GenerateSalt(12)).
```

12 é o custo padrão. Quanto maior o custo mais lento será para ataques do tipo rainbow tables, mas também para processamento da geração do hash pelo seu hardware e pelo banco de dados. 
Para verificação:

```
VerifyPassword(campo_senha, banco_senha)
```

Exemplo em VB.NET (pode ser facilmente portado para C#):

```
If sqldatareader.Hasrows Then
   While sqldatareader.Read
   If (Bcrypt.Net.Bcrypt.Verify(txtPassword.text, 
       sqldatareader.Item("password"))) then
       MsgBox("Valid Credentials")
     else
       MsgBox("Invalid Credentials")
   End if
   End While
   sqldatareader.Close()
End If
```

sqldatareader: datareader que pode ser do mysql, sql, postgresql, etc. 
Para guardar a senha no banco de dados use varchar(255) ou nvarchar(255) no caso do sql server.